# What are the universes in which Doctor Strange travels in “Doctor Strange in the Multiverse of Madness”?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, dr-strange-multiverse-of-madness

While escaping from Wanda Doctor Strange and America Chavez travel to different universes before reaching 838 universe. What are these universes?

Comment: All invented for the film, I expect.

Comment: Definitely interesting ones from what I remember.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> In response to the Scarlet Witch's attack on Kamar-Taj in Doctor
> Strange 2, America's powers activated which sent her and Stephen
> across the multiverse. Before reaching their destination, several
> different universes are featured in a wild ride that sees the duo
> reacting to different environments one after the other. While each
> universe is only briefly shown, each one has its own unique
> distinctions.
>
> Chavez and Strange first entered a reality with the MCU version of the
> Living Tribunal before jumping to a world made of crystals, followed
> by a forest filled with giant flying bugs. They then found themselves
> underwater with all sorts of sea creatures before being greeted by a
> jungle with battling dinosaurs (potentially the comics' Savage Land).
> Continuing through a reality where their bodies started separating
> into cubes, they turned into multi-colored blobs of paint in the next
> reality. Other realities included an old-timey universe with zeppelins
> and old-fashioned cars, a reality with giant pillars and what might
> have been Stonehenge, a world of volcanoes, one made of tubes, one
> featuring dark smoke with violins, two resembling futuristic cities,
> one made entirely of large skeletons, and one resembling 1960s-70's
> era comic book art.

So, there were I think 16 universes in that sequence. Source: [*All 22 Universes In Doctor Strange 2*. Screen Rant.](https://screenrant.com/doctor-strange-multiverse-madness-universes-explained/)