# Does the MCU have an equivalent to DC's living universe?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, dr-strange-multiverse-of-madness

In the DCAU the universe has a level of consciousness and awareness, it is able to enforce certain laws governing personal conduct and has on several occasions empowered champions such as the Spectre to engorce them on its behalf.

For example, when John Constantine was emprisoned in the House of Mystery, and then to a worse fate as yet unconfirmed, for rewriting history.

Is there an equivalent in the MCU?

For example example, prior to the finale of Multiverse of Madness, Strange uses Dream Walking to possess the corpse of an alternative version of himself from another world in the Multiverse.

He's clearly aware that doing so is wrong, and that there someone or something will attempt to enforce consequences on him because of it.

He is subsequently attacked by the spirits of the dead, who specifically state that what he is doing is forbidden.

The sorcerers themselves don't seem to be aware of what Strange was doing and don't seem to be in a position to stop him. At least from what we're shown on screen. And the magic book that he's using is specifically stated to be a villainous artefact that doesn't make any attempts on screen to restrain the user.

Does this demonstrates that there is an equivalent?

As of yet the existence of the The One Above All remains conjecture in the MCU and had never been confirmed in franchise Canon.

Answer (score 4):

Yes. In Marvel cosmology, each universe has a level of consciousness and awareness, personified in a being called [Eternity](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Eternity). The same being has appeared in the MCU, specifically in *Thor: Love and Thunder*.

There is also a being in charge of enforcement across the multiverse, the [Living Tribunal](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Living_Tribunal). Statues of him/it have appeared in both [*Thor: Love and Thunder*](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/265750) and [*Doctor Strange in the Multiverse of Madness*](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/265068).

There is also a single multiversity [Eternity](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Eternity_(Multiverse)), but this concept has not appeared in the MCU to date.